# How can I save data differently sorted in a .json file, where should that be stored, and how can I retrieve it?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm new to android developing and created an "eventlogger" app where you start by choosing an infinite number of Events in this Activity:

[image]

All the Events are added into an ArrayList called "**events**" that looks like that:

```
[Event 1, Event 2, Event 3]
```

In the next Activity you can start a timer, press the buttons and log the times as strings into an Arraylist of Arraylists.

[image]

The ArrayList of Arraylists is named "**allEventsList**" is created

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allActionsList;
```

and then filled with data (times), so it looks like that

```
[[00:00:01, 00:00:09, 00:00:12], [00:00:04, 00:00:07, 00:00:14], [00:00:03, 00:00:06, 00:00:15]]
```

At the end I want to safe that in a .json file that looks like that

```
{
"events":{
    "Event 1":["00:00:01", "00:00:09", "00:00:12"],
    "Event 2":["00:00:04", "00:00:07", "00:00:14"],
    "Event 3":["00:00:03", "00:00:06", "00:00:15"]

}
```

How can I write my data in a .json file and how can I retrieve it later on and where should I store it?

Comment: SQLite would probably fit your applications needs better than json files. And with SQLite there is no concerns about "..where should I store it".

Comment: @Barns That could be true but I need my application to create a JSON file for further use outside of Androids Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a way to do it:

```
private String convertToJsonString(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allActionsList) 
{
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject events = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray eventX;
    int count = 1;
    String key;

    try {
        for(ArrayList<String> array : allActionsList){
            key = String.format("Event %d", count);
            eventX = new JSONArray();
            for(String s : array){
                eventX.put(s);
            }
            events.put(key, eventX);
            count++;
        }
        jObj.put("events", events);

    } catch(Exception e){
        // failed somewhere to create JSON object
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jObj.toString();
}
```

After converting to String you can just save it to a file.

Then you can read it back from file as a string and build your JSON object back like this:

```
JSONObject events = new JSONObject(<string read from file>);
```

Hope this works for you.